# How can I make my WordPress site redirect to subdomain once successfully login they will redirect back to root domain

Tags: redirect

When users visit my site they should login first through login form which i created in subdomain, once successfully login they will be redirected back to my root domain.

This is my subdomain -> http://login.anytimegear.co/ 
This is my rootdomain -> http://www.anytimegear.co/

This is my custom login form code.

```php
$errorMsg = "";
$validUser = $_SESSION["login"] === true;
if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
  $validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "12345";
  if(!$validUser) $errorMsg = "<div style='padding-bottom:25px;color:#d88686;text-align:center;'>Invalid Username & Password.</div>";
  else $_SESSION["login"] = true;
}

if($validUser) {
    header("location: http://www.anytimegear.co/login/");
    }
?>
```

and this is my code to redirect when user visited my site

```php
add_action( 'get_header', 'wpq_my_redirection' );

function wpq_my_redirection() {

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://login.anytimegear.co/ ', 302 ); die();

    }

}
```

This code has an error of too many redirects and I think the problem here it is because the code is redirecting back in forth.

How can I make login form When succesfully login they will redirected back to the root domain without having an issue of "too many redirects".

Comment: First question why do you need the login in a subdomain and then send to a login page on the normal domain? Are they both sharing the same WordPress database? If not try this https://oscarliang.com/multiple-wordpress-sites-share-login/ you wont need to redirect to the login as the user will be logged in on redirect to the other installation.

Comment: We want to have a double login form for that, the site wont be visible to any user and for this login form it wont be conflict when the customer try create account or use the guest account 
No. 2 reason only those users are have the previlege to see the website products.
Is it possible to have two login forms? the wp-admin and my custom login form on the same root folder? thanks a lot :)